# Program won't output into proper columns from a TSV File

Tags: c++

I am importing a `TSV` file. I'm having troubles outputting the data from the file into proper columns and titles aligned with it. When it outputs, it just outputs straight down instead of being in a line horizontally.

(Apologies on how the code is looking on this post)

How its outputting:

```
1

1

Allen, Miss. Elisabeth Walton

female

29

0

0

24160

211.3375

B5

S

2
```

How I would like it to output:

```
PClass | Survived | Name | Sex | Age | Sibsp | Parch | Ticket | Fare | Cabin | Embarked | Boat | Body |  Home.Dest

1 1 Allen, Miss. Elisabeth Walton Female 29 0 0 24160 211.2275 B5 S 2
```

Here is a snippet of my code with the issue:

```cpp
int LoadPassengers(string f)

{

    int recCount = 0;

    string lineRead;

    ifstream myIFS;

    myIFS.open(f);

    bool headerRead = false;

    if (myIFS.is_open())
    {
            while (getline(myIFS, lineRead))
            {

                if (headerRead)
                {
                    passengers.push_back(ExtractPassengerInfo(lineRead, "\t"));
                    recCount++;
                }

                else headerRead = true;

            }   
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File did not open successfully. Critical Error \n";
        return 0;
    }

    return recCount;
}

Passenger ExtractPassengerInfo(string s, string d)
{
    size_t pos = 0;

    string token;

    vector<string> tokens;

    //Passenger p;

    int counter = 0;

    while ((pos = s.find(d)) != string::npos)

    {
        token = s.substr(0, pos);

        cout << token << endl;

        tokens.push_back(token);

        s.erase(0, pos + d.length());
    }
    tokens.push_back(s);
    Passenger p(stoi(tokens[0]), stoi(tokens[1]), tokens[2], tokens[3], stod(tokens[4]));
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Remove endl while printing token i.e. use,  cout << token << " ";  instead. And use cout<< endl; just after the while loop ends.

Comment: Thank worked perfectly, thank you for your input <33333